# Custom Startup Window unity3d For Stand alone windows

Tags: c#, unityscript, screen-resolution, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a custom Startup window Or Before start Window for unity3d Standalone. 
I do not know how to start Working on It i have Researched but got noting that can point me on the direction or a Kick start. 
Is it even Possible to Do it As i have seen option in Player Settings--> Display Resolution Dialog-->Hidden By default But how dose it work and how i can set up my own window

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Personal edition, you can't do a true customized start screen, as per their licenses page: https://unity3d.com/get-unity.  You also cannot turn off the default Unity startup screen without using the Professional edition.

The `Player Settings` -> `Display Resolution Dialog` -> `Hidden by Default` options is to enable/disable a screen allowing the player to set the resolution before game start.  Allowing the player to do this can have some undesired effects, depending on how you've set up your game's resolution.  On this resolution screen, you can set a splash image by scrolling down the `Player Settings` inspector a bit.

To make a pseudo-startup screen that occurs after the actual Unity startup is not actually difficult.  Take the image you want for your startup window, put it on a quad.  Set your camera so that the quad fills the whole camera space.  Add some light and you're done.  You can add effects or animation as well.  There are a number of other ways but this is probably the easiest.

Edit: I only have the Personal edition myself so I can't confirm any of the stuff in the following link works firsthand, but I expect you will find it and/or the links it contains to be very helpful in your efforts (the links referenced in it give quite a few worthwhile looking suggestions to accomplish it that I am unable to test): 
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72087/can-i-legally-remove-the-default-unity-splash-screen-by-removing-it-from-the-apk

Comment: i have unity pro and as i understand what you are trying to say is that before my main scene i have to call another scene in which i can make the menu or etc, if yes then i am asking for a way to display window before unity starts as it happens when you open it right now , is there any way to do that

Comment: @SyedAnwarFahim Correct.  See the update to my answer above; it looks to be possible, if annoying.